# How to avoid polyglossia's verbosity when reading the AUX file

Tags: polyglossia, hebrew

In the terminal output of the compilation of a file containing Hebrew and consisting of 79 pages, I get 5,857 times the message

```
Setting \\if@calendar@hebrew
```

Therefore compilation is very slow, since this message has to be displayed 5,857 times.

In the log file I get a longer message:

```
 Setting \if@calendar@hebrew Setting \if@calendar@hebrew Setting \if@calendar@hebrew Setting \if@calendar@hebrew
Package polyglossia Info: Option: english variant=american (with additional patterns).
Package polyglossia Info: Option: english variant=american (with additional patterns).
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 9028.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sffamily on input line 9028.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 9028.
Package polyglossia Info: Option: english variant=american (with additional patterns).
Package polyglossia Info: Option: english variant=american (with additional patterns).
```

The line numbers in fact refer to the AUX file, in which one has the code

```
\@writefile{toc}{\selectlanguage *[numerals=arabic,calendar=gregorian,marcheshvan=false,fullyear=false]{hebrew}}
\@writefile{lof}{\selectlanguage *[numerals=arabic,calendar=gregorian,marcheshvan=false,fullyear=false]{hebrew}}
\@writefile{lot}{\selectlanguage *[numerals=arabic,calendar=gregorian,marcheshvan=false,fullyear=false]{hebrew}}
\selectlanguage *[variant=usmax]{english}
\@writefile{toc}{\selectlanguage *[variant=usmax]{english}}
\@writefile{lof}{\selectlanguage *[variant=usmax]{english}}
\@writefile{lot}{\selectlanguage *[variant=usmax]{english}}
```

This means I'm drowned by a message that is triggered from the AUX file.

How can I avoid this message?

PS. I tried the package option `verbose=false`, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: That is not the only issue with polyglossia and aux file. Among other things, it may write commands there, without first checking so see whether polyglossia is still in use (not a big problem, though). Hopefully the package developers will see your question.

Comment: without an example it is difficult to test, but consider to update, see https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/593